# Android Http Post - Json - respond error bad request

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to do a post to the server. But all I get is an answer: Bad request. I am really new to this. I've done some other examples and it worked fine but this doesn't.

Server Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/restfulservice/alarm/start", method=RequestMethod.POST,
            headers={"Accept=application/json"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public @ResponseBody AlarmStartResponse startAlarm(@RequestParam("alarmStartRequestJson") String alarmStartRequestJson,
                                                       @RequestParam("apiKey") String apiKey)
```

Android Code:

```
private class AsyncPOSTer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://mydomain/restfulservice/alarm/start");
        try {
            List<NameValuePair> np = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            np.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", "Jke"));
            np.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deviceId", "JkeOpo"));
            np.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pairedDeviceId", "JkeSam"));
            np.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Jokke"));
            np.add(new BasicNameValuePair("telephoneNumber", "Phone"));
            np.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alarmInstructions", "alarm instructions"));
            np.add(new BasicNameValuePair("whenRaisedLatitude", "60.155229"));
            np.add(new BasicNameValuePair("whenRaisedLongitude", "15.199038"));
            np.add(new BasicNameValuePair("whenRaisedAccuracy", "33.000"));
            np.add(new BasicNameValuePair("streetAddress", "Biskopsv 7a"));
            np.add(new BasicNameValuePair("zipCode", "12345"));
            np.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", "City"));
            np.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country", "Sweden"));
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(np);
            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            post.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (responseCode == 200) {
                Log.d(TAG, "200");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "NOT 200");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the exact error message? is it a http error from the server or a log entry or what is it exactly?

Comment: HTTP Status 400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Comment: then you are constructing a POST packet that is not valid (not standard conform). Check other answer from hamitana

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the same request using any HTTP client in browser(with plugins like POSTMAN, DHC etc in Chrome)? Just to make sure that you are passing all the parameters in the JSON which is required.

Also there's an android app called 'REST Client for Android' wherein you can create the HTTP request and check if all the headers and parameters are correct. If it works there, it should work here as well(considering that your code is correct).

I do not develop for android but I'm telling this based on my experience on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update

```
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json")
```

to

```
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

to send as JSON format

Comment: Does not help, I think the problem is, where to put the apiKey since the server are requesting: (@RequestParam("alarmStartRequestJson") String alarmStartRequestJson,                                                      @RequestParam("apiKey") String apiKey)